# Split string in Rust, treating consecutive delimiters as one

Tags: rust

How do I split a string in Rust such that contiguous delimiters are collapsed into one? For example:

```rust
"1  2 3".splitX(" ")
```

should yield this `Vec`: `["1", "2", "3"]` (when collected from the Split object, or any other intermediate object there may be). This example is for whitespace but we should be able to extend this for other delimiters too.

I believe we can use `.filter()` to remove empty items after using `.split()`, but it would be cleaner if it could be done as part of the original `.split()` directly. I obviously searched this thoroughly and am surprised I can't find the answer anywhere.

I know for whitespace we already have `split_whitespace()` and `split_ascii_whitespace()`, but I am looking for a solution that works for a general delimiter string.

Comment: Splitting like this is clean and easy... as long as you don't want to use the standard `Split` struct which is not dedicated to this kind of splitting. Why this constraint ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Sorry I do not want the `Split` struct. I only want the final `Vec`, I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: There's really no problem with `let output: Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").filter(|s| !s.is_empty()).collect();`: it's fast, clean, and readable. So it's unclear why you're looking for something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard solution is to use `split` then `filter`:

```rust
let output: Vec<&str> = input
    .split(pattern)
    .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
    .collect();
```

This is fast and clear.

You can also use a regular expression to avoid the filter step:

```rust
let output: Vec<&str> = regex::Regex::new(" +").unwrap()
    .split(input)
    .collect();
```

If it's in a function which will be called several times, you can avoid repeating the Regex compilation with lazy_regex:

```rust
let output: Vec<&str> = lazy_regex::regex!(" +")
    .split(input)
    .collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, by far the cleanest way is to write `.split(" ").filter(|s| !s.is_empty())`. It works for all separators and the intent is obvious from reading the code.

If that's too "ugly", you could perhaps pull it into a trait:

```rust
trait SplitNonEmpty {
  // you might want to define your own struct for the return type
  fn split_non_empty<'a, P>(&self, p: P) where P: Pattern<'a> -> ...;
}

impl SplitNonEmpty for &str {
  // ...
}
```

If it's very important that this function returns a `Split`, you might need to refactor your code to use traits more; do you really care that it was created by splitting a string, or do you care that you can iterate over it? If so, maybe that function should take a `impl IntoIterator<&'a str>`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to clarify that my function need not return `Split`, only `Vec` is sufficient. I have edited my question to clarify that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, `split` and `filter` or with `regex` is better here. But there is one pattern which can be used `flat_map`. Though in this context it doesn't add much value.

```
fn main() {
    let output: Vec<&str> = "1  2 3"
        .split(" ")
        .flat_map(|x| if !x.is_empty() { Some(x) } else { None })
        .collect();
    println!("{:#?}", output)
}
```

You can use this pattern, say, if you want to parse these strings as numbers and ignore error values.

```
fn main() {
    let output: Vec<i32> = "1  2 3"
        .split(" ")
        .flat_map(|x| x.parse())
        .collect();
    println!("{:#?}", output)
}
```

All `flat_map` cares is closure to return something which implements `IntoIterator`